# Microsoft.SharePoint.Client Online FieldType Mapping

Tags: sharepoint, mapping, fieldtype

I am attempting to push values into a SharePoint Online List. 
A couple questions:

1. If I create this code using SharePoint online structures, will that also work for companies that have their own on-premise servers? Or do I have to create a whole new code base to support that also? Seems there are some large difference between `SPFieldType` and `FieldType`, or is the code automatically making that change?
2. In mapping `FieldType`, I am looking for some reference or code that explains the proper mapping for the various field types. I have seen these for the Sister product SharePoint 2013, such as :

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21801.sharepoint-a-complete-guide-to-getting-and-setting-fields-using-c.aspx

But the differences between 2013 `SPFieldType` and the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldType` seem rather large. Is there something corresponding that describes what each field type requires for the values to be successful in `FieldType`?

Here is an example my existing code, and what I am still missing:

```
       public string ToString(Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldType ColumnType)
    {
        switch (ColumnType)
        {
            case Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldType.Boolean:
                // 0 or 1, or "true" or "false"???
                break;
            case Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldType.Calculated:
                // No idea!
                break;
            case Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldType.Choice:
                // No idea!
                break;
            case Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldType.Computed:
                // No idea!
                break;
            case Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldType.Currency:
                // No idea!
                break;
            case Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldType.DateTime:
                return GetDateTimeValue().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

            case Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldType.File:
                // No idea!
                break;
            case Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldType.GridChoice:
                // No idea!
                break;
            case Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldType.Guid:
                // No idea!
                break;
            case Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldType.Integer:
                return GetIntValue().ToString(); 

            case Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldType.Lookup:
                // No idea!
                break;
            case Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldType.MultiChoice:
                // No idea!
                break;
            case Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldType.Note:
                return GetStringValue();
            case Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldType.Number:
                return GetDoubleValue().ToString();
            case Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldType.Text:
                return GetStringValue();
            case Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldType.User:
                // No idea!
                break;
            case Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldType.URL:
                // No idea!
                break;
            // No Idea what to do for these
            case Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldType.WorkflowEventType:
            case Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldType.WorkflowStatus:
            case Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldType.AllDayEvent:
            case Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldType.Attachments:
            case Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldType.ThreadIndex:
            case Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldType.Threading:
            case Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldType.PageSeparator:
            case Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldType.Recurrence:
            case Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldType.Invalid:
            case Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldType.ContentTypeId:
            case Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldType.Counter:
            case Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldType.CrossProjectLink:
            case Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldType.MaxItems:
            case Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldType.ModStat:
            case Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldType.Error:
                break;
            default:
                return GetStringValue();
        }
        return GetStringValue();
    }
```

The missing methods just convert values from my data into the appropriate strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server Object Model and .NET Client Object Model are different.
If you want to push values into a SharePoint Online List, I suggest you use Pnp- PowerShell to achieve it.

[Add-PnPListItem](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/blob/master/Documentation/Add-PnPListItem.md)

About the Field type, please check the code from [GetField](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/blob/master/Commands/Fields/GetField.cs).

If you don't want to use Pnp-PowerShell, you need convert the Server Object Model code to Client Object Model code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Pretty sure I am using Client Object Model (also called CSOM???) since I will not be deploying the code on a SharePoint server and it is working. From what I have read Pnp-PowerShell is based on CSOM, so that means it should work for both - online and on-premise SharePoint?

Comment: We can't use Server Side Object Model(SSOM) in SharePoint Online. We can use Client side Object Model(CSOM) both in SharePoint Online and On-Premise.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks!